# Finding the remainder of $x^{y^z}\pmod k$ if $k$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to find the remainder of $x^{y^z}\pmod{k}$ if $k$ is prime.

I am trying to use little Fermat theorems but I cannot really generalize the $x,y,z$. I need an general algorithm to automate this type of problems.

Answer (score 1):

If $\rm\:p\:$ is prime then $\rm\: mod\ p\!:\ x\not\equiv 0\:\Rightarrow\:x^{\large{p-1}}\!\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ x^{\large {n}}\!\equiv x^{\large{n\ mod\ p\!-\!1}}$

When $\rm\: n = y^{\large z}\:$ one can evaluate $\rm\: y^{\large z}\ mod\ p\!-\!1\:$ either by repeated squaring, or by factoring and using CRT and/or Euler or Carmichael's theorem, or by other specialized techniques.

Comment: is there a better optimized one for $y^zmod(p-1)$